# gstreamer low latency audio capture- windows

Tags: windows, audio, gstreamer, latency

I am trying to use gstreamer for low-latency streaming purpose under windows, and what I am facing now is the audio capturing latency.

I tested audio capture latency by creating a loopback pipeline as follows:

gst-launch-1.0 directsoundsrc ! directsoundsink

However, the audio latency is higher than expected, more than ~200ms. I guess the directsoundsrc do some buffering for the audio samples, I tried to tune its parameters in a hope to get better latency (buffer-time/latency-time) but the results were still not applicable.

Does anyone knows better way to capture low-latency audio and feed it to gstreamer pipeline than the one I am using?

Comment: why do you think the directsoundsink is not doing the latency (to the testing pipe) ?

Comment: Good note, I also suspected that before. I tried to implement my own sink, and I directed audio samples to the sound card directly, but still I found there is a delay.